# Name of latex font using in the document (see picture)

Tags: fonts, packages, greek

What is the name of the font used in this latex document? And how can I have the same type of greek symbols?

Thanks a lot ! [image]

Comment: if you have that pdf you can use your pdf viewer font menu or the pdffonts utility to list the exact fonts used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Comment: Have you tried [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to find out the commands for specific symbols?